# how to use own material design icons with materializecss?

Tags: css, material-design, materialize

I need to know how to add own mdi icons in custom classes. the provided mdi classes provided don't meet my expectations.

How can i add those and use them like the default one

```
<i class="mdi-image-facebook"></i>
<i class="mdi-image-linkedin"></i>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'd probably have to make your own. I think they use SVG Sprites so it might be a larger job that n you are linking.

Comment: that annoying ! I wanted just to add materialize icons of social networs such as facebook, linked in, twitter ! That don't exist as mdi in google material design

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, the is an alternative solution provided by this website. It's include preety much a good number of icons such as social buttons.

http://materialdesignicons.com/getting-started

You just have to add this css link to get the icons and add them as classes

```
<link href="css/materialdesignicons.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and

```
<i class="mdi mdi-facebook-box"></i>  <!-- facebook box -->
```

Comment: In my case, the icon doesn't appear. I think there is a conflict with my `materialize.css` (when I inspect the `i` tag, I see that reference).

Comment: Which reference you talk about @JCarlos ?

Comment: In the developer console (chrome), I see the `i` tag ignoring the `materialdesignicons` file (because I have another css with icons). But, I found other useful link: http://codepen.io/luciarrno/pen/RPVgaJ

Answer (score 2):

Just include this stylesheet:

```
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

you can now use materializecss' icon tags. sample below :)

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="material-icons right">cloud</i>button</a>
```

for more info visit: http://materializecss.com/icons.html

Comment: is there a way to locally reference the icon file?

Comment: yes there is. you can use :before and :after pseudo elements in css. you can refer on how to use these pseudo elements on [http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/CSS-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-practice](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/CSS-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-practice)